# Condition on a field that makes every subring an integrally closed domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

> I want to know what condition would need to be additionally imposed on a field to make every subring of the field an integrally closed domain.

Comment: Such a field $k$ must be algebraic over its prime field $k_0$ - if $x \in k$ is transcendental over $k_0$, then $k_0[x^2,x^3]$ is not integrally closed. If the prime field is $\mathbb{F}_p$, then being algebraic is also sufficient.

Comment: Solved on [MO](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/19521/for-which-fields-k-is-every-subring-of-k).